# Find $\alpha, \beta$ s.t. the following is minimized

Tags: calculus, functional-analysis, multivariable-calculus, optimization

Hello I would like to find $\alpha,\beta$ s.t.

$$
e(\alpha,\beta) = ||\sqrt{1+\gamma^2}-\alpha-\beta\gamma||_\infty = || f_{\alpha,\beta}||_{\infty}
$$
Is minimum (consider $\gamma \in [0,1)$, $\alpha, \beta \geq 0$, in $\mathbb{R}$).
I tried the following

$$
f(\gamma)_{\alpha,\beta} = \sqrt{1+\gamma^2}-\alpha-\beta\gamma \Rightarrow \frac{df_{\alpha,\beta}}{d\gamma} = \frac{\gamma}{\sqrt{1-\gamma^2}} - \beta \Rightarrow \gamma_0 = \frac{\beta^2}{\sqrt{1-\beta^2}},
$$

If I put this solution into $f$ then I have

$$
f_{\alpha,\beta}(\gamma_0) = g(\alpha,\beta) = \sqrt{1-\beta^2} - \alpha
$$

Assuming $\beta \neq - 1$ the function $g$ is differentiable, so I use the gradient method to find the stationary points:

$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{l}
\frac{\partial g}{\partial \alpha} = -1 \\
\frac{\partial g}{\partial \beta} = \frac{\beta}{\sqrt{1-\beta^2}}
\end{array}
\right.
$$

I'm puzzled because I don't know if I've done everything correctly so far.
Is it correct?

Comment: What is the usage of $\|.\|_\infty$ if $\alpha,\beta$ and $\gamma$ are scalars?

Comment: The function $f_{\alpha,\beta}$ is defined in $[0,1)$, $\gamma$ is not a constant, is a variable.